# Android crashing on ListPreference

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add a listpreference to my application. My xml code is the following:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/calendarsettings">
    <CheckBoxPreference android:key="syncWithCalendar"
        android:title="@string/setting_calendarsync" android:summary="@string/setting_calendarsync"></CheckBoxPreference>
    <CheckBoxPreference android:key="calendarAlarm"
        android:title="@string/settings_calendaralarm" android:summary="@string/settings_calendaralarm"></CheckBoxPreference>
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/filters">
    <ListPreference android:key="dayFilter" android:title="@string/dayfilter"
        android:summary="@string/dayfilter" android:entries="@array/dayFilterArray"
        android:entryValues="@array/dayFilterValues" />
</PreferenceCategory>
 </PreferenceScreen>
```

And my array values are:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
<string-array name="dayFilterArray">
 <item>a</item>
 <item>b</item>
 <item>c</item>
 <item>d</item>
 <item>e</item>
 <item>f</item>
 <item>g</item>
 </string-array>
  <string-array name="dayFilterValues">
 <item>0</item>
 <item>3</item>
 <item>7</item>
 <item>14</item>
 <item>30</item>
 <item>90</item>
 <item>365</item>
  </string-array>
 </resources>
```

However when I try to enter my preference menu it crashes with the following exception:

```
10-03 20:27:56.938: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1111): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Which refers to this line of code:

```
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
```

Any thoughts on this and why is it happening? Thanks.

FULL STACK TRACE:

```
10-03 21:13:06.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-03 21:13:06.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cPreferencesActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
10-03 21:13:06.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1748)
10-03 21:13:06.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1764)
10-03 21:13:06.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
10-03 21:13:06.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1002)
10-03 21:13:06.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-03 21:13:06.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
10-03 21:13:06.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
10-03 21:13:06.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-03 21:13:06.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
10-03 21:13:06.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
10-03 21:13:06.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
10-03 21:13:06.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-03 21:13:06.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
10-03 21:13:06.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getString(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:203)
10-03 21:13:06.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at android.preference.Preference.getPersistedString(Preference.java:1367)
10-03 21:13:06.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at android.preference.ListPreference.onSetInitialValue(ListPreference.java:278)
10-03 21:13:06.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at android.preference.Preference.dispatchSetInitialValue(Preference.java:1283)
10-03 21:13:06.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at android.preference.Preference.onAttachedToHierarchy(Preference.java:1095)
10-03 21:13:06.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at android.preference.PreferenceGroup.addPreference(PreferenceGroup.java:156)
10-03 21:13:06.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at android.preference.PreferenceGroup.addItemFromInflater(PreferenceGroup.java:97)
10-03 21:13:06.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at android.preference.PreferenceGroup.addItemFromInflater(PreferenceGroup.java:38)
10-03 21:13:06.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:488)
10-03 21:13:06.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:493)
10-03 21:13:06.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:326)
10-03 21:13:06.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:263)
10-03 21:13:06.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:269)
10-03 21:13:06.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceActivity.java:1333)
10-03 21:13:06.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at PreferencesActivity.onCreate(PreferencesActivity.java:33)
10-03 21:13:06.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
10-03 21:13:06.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1712)
10-03 21:13:06.828: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3045):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: This solution worked for me:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4644908/1665320

Comment: just adding this could be due to if you are returning an integer as Default value from `Object onGetDefaultValue(TypedArray a, int index) `

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have persisted an `Integer` before in the preferences. `ListActivity` expects a `String` so cast fails.

Just call this code at the beginning of `onCreate` to remove the wrong value and this should be fixed:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().remove("dayFilter").commit();
```

If it still happens than you're probably using the `dayFilter` twice as key for different preferences or do persist that key on your own as `Integer` somewhere in your code.

If this doesn't work then try to remove your preferences from this locations:

```
/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/YOUR_PREFS_NAME.xml
/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME_preferences.xml

// on some devices
/dbdata/databases/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/YOUR_PREFS_NAME.xml
```

If this does fail, try to uninstall application so they should be removed (this doesn't work on my Samsung Galaxy S - shared preferences are not deleted...)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but that didn't work. Also I've checked the XML and I'm only using the dayFilter as key one time.

Comment: Please post your full stacktrace then. So we can see where this exception is thrown.

Comment: I've included it in my initial post.

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted you mate. How can I fix it then? The thing is I tried using strings where the numbers are and the same error occured.

Comment: I already described the problem. It's an integer value persisted in `dayFilter`. I admit I didn't test the code in my answer (I assumed it would do the job). You have to delete it from there. A root access to your preference file on the device would solve that too. Or simply rename `dayFilter` and ignore the wrong value which is set.

Comment: Well I uninstalled the application and it worked like a charm... silly android.

Comment: I updated my answer. I'm sorry, the code didn't work but my update should do the job now.

Comment: Thanks, I did the same thing changed from Switch to List Pref, causing a boolean cast error.  Uninstalled/reinstalled to clear it out.

Comment: I would just uninstall it. Its the quickest and easiest way of handling it. (If it works, as you said, it might not work on every device)

Answer (score -1):

Your XML file isn't written correctly, you declare an array of **strings** but you provide **integers** hence the Cast exception.

```
 <string-array name="dayFilterValues">
 <item>0</item>
...
 <item>365</item>
  </string-array>
```

To fix it simply put quotes around the integer values:

```
<item>"365"</item>
```

Then in your app you need to parse the string into an Integer with:

```
int value = Integer.parseInt(str);
```

Comment: I've tried with strings where the numbers are and it still happens.

Comment: can you post the logcat message when you do this?

Comment: -1 `ListPreference` calls `persistString(value)` internally, so it will always persist a string (never integer)