# Android application AndroidRuntime

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

I am learning how to build an android application and got to this situation:

When i am trying to lunch the Emulator, and pressing on the AboutUs button it works fine, also as the exit. But when i am pressing on the preferences button i get an error:

```
> 01-23 07:40:59.145: E/AndroidRuntime(314): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-23 07:40:59.145: E/AndroidRuntime(314): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jinibox.jinibox/com.jinibox.jinibox.Prefs}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
01-23 07:40:59.145: E/AndroidRuntime(314): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-23 07:40:59.145: E/AndroidRuntime(314): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-23 07:40:59.145: E/AndroidRuntime(314): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-23 07:40:59.145: E/AndroidRuntime(314): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-23 07:40:59.145: E/AndroidRuntime(314): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-23 07:40:59.145: E/AndroidRuntime(314): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-23 07:40:59.145: E/AndroidRuntime(314): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-23 07:40:59.145: E/AndroidRuntime(314): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 07:40:59.145: E/AndroidRuntime(314): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-23 07:40:59.145: E/AndroidRuntime(314): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-23 07:40:59.145: E/AndroidRuntime(314): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-23 07:40:59.145: E/AndroidRuntime(314): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-23 07:40:59.145: E/AndroidRuntime(314): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
01-23 07:40:59.145: E/AndroidRuntime(314): at android.app.ContextImpl$SharedPreferencesImpl.getBoolean(ContextImpl.java:2724)
01-23 07:40:59.145: E/AndroidRuntime(314): at android.preference.Preference.getPersistedBoolean(Preference.java:1425)
01-23 07:40:59.145: E/AndroidRuntime(314): at android.preference.CheckBoxPreference.onSetInitialValue(CheckBoxPreference.java:259)
01-23 07:40:59.145: E/AndroidRuntime(314): at android.preference.Preference.dispatchSetInitialValue(Preference.java:1172)
01-23 07:40:59.145: E/AndroidRuntime(314): at android.preference.Preference.onAttachedToHierarchy(Preference.java:984)
01-23 07:40:59.145: E/AndroidRuntime(314): at android.preference.PreferenceGroup.addPreference(PreferenceGroup.java:156)
01-23 07:40:59.145: E/AndroidRuntime(314): at android.preference.PreferenceGroup.addItemFromInflater(PreferenceGroup.java:97)
01-23 07:40:59.145: E/AndroidRuntime(314): at android.preference.PreferenceGroup.addItemFromInflater(PreferenceGroup.java:38)
01-23 07:40:59.145: E/AndroidRuntime(314): at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:488)
01-23 07:40:59.145: E/AndroidRuntime(314): at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:326)
01-23 07:40:59.145: E/AndroidRuntime(314): at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:263)
01-23 07:40:59.145: E/AndroidRuntime(314): at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:251)
01-23 07:40:59.145: E/AndroidRuntime(314): at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceActivity.java:262)
01-23 07:40:59.145: E/AndroidRuntime(314): at com.jinibox.jinibox.Prefs.onCreate(Prefs.java:12)
01-23 07:40:59.145: E/AndroidRuntime(314): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-23 07:40:59.145: E/AndroidRuntime(314): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-23 07:40:59.145: E/AndroidRuntime(314): ... 11 more
```

Can someone help me please?

**cool_menu.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/aboutUs"
        android:alphabeticShortcut="a"
        android:numericShortcut="1"
        android:title="Abou Us"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/preferences "
        android:title="Preferences"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/exit "
        android:title="Exit"/>

</menu>
```

**menu.java**

```
    package com.jinibox.jinibox;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Menu extends ListActivity {

    String classes[] = { "JiniboxActivity", "TextPlay", "Email", "Camera",
            "Data", };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String jiniboxmenu = classes[position];
        try {
            Class ourClass = Class
                    .forName("com.jinibox.jinibox." + jiniboxmenu);
            Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
            startActivity(ourIntent);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater blowup = getMenuInflater();
        blowup.inflate(R.menu.cool_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.aboutUs:
            Intent i = new Intent("com.jinibox.jinibox.ABOUTUS");
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case R.id.preferences:
            Intent p = new Intent("com.jinibox.jinibox.PREFS");
            startActivity(p);
            break;
        case R.id.exit:
            finish();
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Prefs.java**

```
    package com.jinibox.jinibox;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        //TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
    }
}
```

**prefs.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <EditTextPreference
        android:title="EditText"
        android:key="name"
        android:summary="Enter Your Name" >
    </EditTextPreference>

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:title="Music"
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="chackbox"
        android:summary="Chack This Box" />
    <ListPreference
        android:title="list"
        android:key="list"
        android:summary="This Is A List To Choos From"
        android:entries="@array/list"
        android:entryValues="@array/lvalues">
    </ListPreference>

</PreferenceScreen>

**array.xml**

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="list">
        <item>option 1</item>
        <item>option 2</item>
        <item>option 3</item>
        <item>option 4</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="lvalues">
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
        <item>4</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

**manifest**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jinibox.jinibox"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".JiniboxActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.jinibox.jinibox.JINIBOX" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Menu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.jinibox.jinibox.MENU" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TextPlay"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Email"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Camera"
            android:label="Camera Application"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Data"
            android:label="Data" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".OpenedClass"
            android:label="OpenedClass"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Prefs"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.jinibox.jinibox.PREFS" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AboutUs"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.jinibox.jinibox.ABOUTUS" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: It is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String , You are trying String to Pref class, I suspect it is something related to pref and PREF names you used. I would suggest revisit that logic.

Comment: actually i think you might have an interestingly funny issue. Its a class cast exception right. So the debug output also says that its from a string and its to do with a checkboxpreference which is in your prefs.xml. The only boolean that is being / could be casted is the default value. Can you make a boolean in the resources file and reference it from prefs.xml and see if that works. I doubt it but thats the only thing i got right now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463886/classcastexception-in-preferenceactivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have put some non-boolean value to your `SharedPreference` file (it's default in your case) with `android:key="chackbox"` and then assigned this key to boolean value. Just try changing the CheckBoxPreference key attribute in your `prefs.xml` to another value, let's say `android:key="checkboxMusic"` or change the `SharedPreference` file name with [`setSharedPreferencesName(..)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#setSharedPreferencesName%28java.lang.String%29) method in your Prefs.java onCreate(..) method.

Comment: Thanks! i have changed the key from chackbox the chackboxMusic, and it worked.

Comment: Ur welcome! You [need to accept](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) the answer if it solves your problem.