# Error Cannot be cast string to integer

Tags: java, android, parseint, edittextpreference

I can't change the EditTextPreference value from string to int. I've done in this way:

```
WifiOnOffValue = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("WifiOnOffValue");
String value = WifiOnOffValue.getText().toString();
if(value != null && !value.isEmpty()) {
    try {
        vedit = Integer.parseInt(value);
    } 
    catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        vedit = 0;
    }
}
```

And I get the error `java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java lang.String`... I need convert the value of my EditTextPreference in integer. Thanks

Log:
[image]

Code:

```
        //-- Edittext Wifi
        WifiOnOffValue = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("WifiOnOffValue");

        String value = WifiOnOffValue.getText().toString().trim();
        if(value!=null && !value.isEmpty()){
            try{
                vedit = Integer.parseInt(value);
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                vedit=0;
            }
        }
```

**Solved**.. this was the solution: [ClassCastException in PreferenceActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463886/classcastexception-in-preferenceactivity/4644908#4644908) seems that it stored wrong values.. Now i can start the app and seems goes well.. The solution to me was simply uninstall and reinstall the application.. so strange. Thanks to everybody anyway

Comment: Which line you are getting error? Your error is opposite of the code you have written in try block

Comment: in Integer.parseInt(value) value is not representing any integer eg. if value is some thing like 100,12,30 it will work but if it is hundred, twelve it will throw the exception. Means value does not represent any integer.

Comment: 31, this: `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);` when I declare the layout

Comment: @gusaindpk what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Try using `trim()` function for `value` before converting to `Integer`. There might be some trailing or leading spaces.  It will work fine if value contains only numbers.

Comment: first print the value what exactly it is. if it is some random string it will throw exception. But if it is a proper string representation of integer it will work fine. so please first print the value.

Comment: Also using trim I get the exception.. I print the value now..

Comment: What is the value of the value? :P

Comment: Can you check with a debugger what does String value contains and print it here? It could have non-digit chars

Comment: I can't! It crashes before open the app. It's incredible!!

Answer (score 0):

Could you check the type of variable vedit? Is wrongly declared as String?

Comment: can you post the stack trace from your logcat? It will help others to narrow down issue

Comment: what is the preference type acually? is it of type int? looks like you are trying to fetch an int value from preference as string

Comment: You mean the preference.xml value of edit? i wrote: `android:inputType="number"`

Comment: Not input type. can you post the entire tag from that xml for WifiOnOffValue ?

Comment: I post the whole code i think it's better. Wait a minute

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51652/discussion-between-end-game-and-noone)

Answer (score 0):

try to use `String value = WifiOnOffValue.getText().toString().trim()` and log out to see what the value of `value` is

Comment: I have always the error at same line.. 31: `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);` maybe something wrong in the xml?

Answer (score 0):

Should'nt it be

```
WifiOnOffValue = (EditTextPreference) getPreferenceManager().findPreference("WifiOnOffValue");
```

Comment: Really it's incredible!! Doesn't work!! I'm going crazy!